# Avoiding nested subscribes with combine latest when one observable depends on the result of another

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have three observables I would like to combine into a single stream. However the third observable requires a property from the first observable -- is it possible to combine all three to avoid nested subscribes (for the sake of clarity)?

```
Observable.combineLatest(this.fooService.model, this.barService.model)
  .subscribe(result => {
    //do work

    this.bazService.anotherObservable(result[0].someProperty)
      .subscribe(anotherResult => {
        //do more work
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`switchMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap) and [`map`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map) to do what you want:

```js
Observable
  .combineLatest(this.fooService.model, this.barService.model)
  .switchMap(([foo, bar]) => {
    return bazService
      .anotherObservable(foo.someProperty)
      .map((baz) => [foo, bar, baz]);
  })
  .subscribe(([foo, bar, baz]) => console.log(foo, bar, baz));
```

Whenever the combined `foo` and `bar` observables emit a value, the `baz` service will be called and its result will be futher combined.

Note that `switchMap` will abandon pending `baz` calls if the `foo` or `bar` observables re-emit. If you don't want that behaviour and always want the `baz` result to be emitted, use [`concatMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap) instead of `switchMap`.

Another option is to use [`mergeMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap) instead of `concatMap` - the latter will guarantee that the order of the `baz` calls will be preserved, the former won't.

Comment: awesome answer!

Comment: I had this exact case and have been benchmarking testing etc. 
Thanks so much